# Stepper motor working

Tags: pic, stepper-motor

I wanted to know why a stepper motor requires a driver board and can't just run directly by a pic microcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All motors consists of windings I.e., an inductor. So when you change your voltage from logic high to logic low or vice versa it opposes the change in current inside it. This opposition is done by creating a reverse current through your circuit. This reverse current in most cases is quite high which is beyond the range of microcontroller handling capability. So in order for this not to happen people use drivers.

Drivers can be transistors, optoisolators,etc. They all kind of isolate microcontroller from the reverse current but still giving you the controlling capability.

Also the required currents to drive motors cannot be fed by microcontrollers and drivers also help this way too.

Comment: Jasser I already asked that can we run it via transistor?

Comment: Well yes you can do that, but your transistors should be able to handle all the maximum current in your circuit. Keep flyback diodes to protect from reverse currents. Generally the normal transistors we use cannot handle motor current and therefore we go for drivers which contains opamp and other stuff. Also if you want to drive it using transistors, use power transistors which will have high power handling capability

Comment: @user103110 - "I already asked that " Well, no you didn't. Please read your question again. You stated that a driver board is needed, and asked why "can't just run directly by a pic microcontroller ".

Comment: He is new and might have been talking about the comment in transistor's answer @WhatRoughBeast

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that a bicycle dynamo can't run an office block: power handling ability.

The PIC micro output pins can switch up to a few tens of milli-amps (thousandths of an amp) at 5 V maximum. A stepper motor will require several amps and generally at higher voltages.

The driver board takes low-power control signals from the PIC (or any other micro) and uses them to control power from a source of high-enough power to drive the motor.

Comment: Thanks , but I want to know what's special stuff in driver board ,                                        if amps and voltage are problem we can run by transistor which is fed by a output signal in series with current limiting resistor and this signal we can take from the microcontroller! Or this is not a proper way to use ?

Comment: You're on the right track. The driver board will consist of all the transistors, resistors and protection diodes required to do the conversion all in one neat package.

Answer (score 0):

Most steppers require **far** more current and will benefit from more voltage (chopped) than a microcontroller can supply.

However it's perfectly feasible to drive a **very** small stepper directly from a microcontroller with beefy output drivers (20mA).

[image: http://christopherbradshaw.net/The_Project_Bin/2005%20Trailblazer%20Instrument%20Cluster%20Repair%20Inside%20Stepper%20Motor.jpg]